# ion-segment-button: dynamically checked not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ng-switch

In my angular application I tried to dynamically generate ion-segment-buttons for each day of the week and then check today initially.

template:

```
<ion-segment class="ion-padding" (ionChange)="onChangeDay($event)">
<div [ngSwitch]="weekday" *ngFor="let weekday of workweek">
  <ion-segment-button *ngSwitchCase="workweek[today]" [value]="weekday" checked>{{weekday}}</ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button *ngSwitchDefault [value]="weekday">{{weekday}}</ion-segment-button>
</div>
```

relevant ts code:

```
public workweek = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri']; 
public today = new Date().getDay()-1;

onChangeDay(event: Event) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using ngModel

template:

```
<ion-segment class="ion-padding" (ionChange)="onChangeDay($event)" [(ngModel)]="segment">
   <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let weekday of workweek; let i = index;" [value]="i"> 
   {{weekday}}</ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

typescript code:

```
public workweek = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri']; 
public today = new Date().getDay()-1;

onChangeDay(event: Event) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ion-segment value="all">
    <ion-segment-button value="all">
      <ion-label>All</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>

    <ion-segment-button value="bookable">
      <ion-label>Bookable</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
```